# Best way to get and use Stored authentication token in React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am using react-hooks and storing authentication token in Asyncstorage, I am looking for the best way to get the stored token in order to be used all over my App's component 
I tried to retrieve it in `useEffect` hook as shown below

```
const [token, setToken] = useState(""); 
useEffect(() => {

    getToken();

}, [token])


const getToken = async () => {
    const storedObject = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    if(storedObject) {
    const token  = JSON.parse(storedObject).token ; 
    setToken(token);
    } 
}
```

The issue with the above approach is that in some cases especially when I navigate to the component I do not get the token. I also tried to put the above code in a Context API and access it by using  `useContext` hook but the result it same

Comment: are you using redux ???

Comment: No, I am not using it